# Using one of the solutions of coupled differential equations as a factor in an integrand

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have

```
pde1 = -y1''[x] - (2*y1'[x])/x + ((y1[x])^3 + y2[x])*y1[x] == 0;
pde2 = y2''[x] + (2*y2'[x])/x - (y1[x])^3 == 0
sol = 
  NDSolve[
    {pde1, pde2, 
     y1[1] == 0.001, y2[1] == -0.001, 
     y1'[0.001] == 0.001, y2'[0.001] == 0.001}, 
    {y1, y2}, {x, 30}]
```

I need to plot the values of `Integrate[y1[u] u^2, {u, xmin, x}]` over the domain `{xmin, xmax}`.

Comment: Try **Plot[Evaluate[y1[x] x^2 /. sol], {x, 0.001, 30}]**

Comment: thank you but i need the integration of the solution of( y1)*x^2

Answer (score 4):

You can augment your system to

```
pde1 = -y1''[x] - (2*y1'[x])/x + (10^-19 (y1[x])^2y2[x])*y1[x] == 0; 
pde2 = y2''[x] + (2*y2'[x])/x - (10^-25)*(y1[x])^2 == 0;
pde3 = y3'[x] == y1[x] x^2;
sol = NDSolve[{pde1, pde2, pde3, y1[1] == 0.001, y2[1] == -0.001, y1'[0.001] == 0.001, y2'[0.001] == 0.001, y3[0.001] == 0}, {y1, y2,y3}, {x, 30}]
```

and then

```
Plot[Evaluate[y3[x] /. sol], {x, 0.001, 30}]
```

Comment: thank you so much it's so helpful